# Hibernate IllegalArgumentException persistence.xml does not exist - unit test without persistence.xml

Tags: persistence.xml, openejb

I am using OpenEJB in some unit (integration) tests for my database module, following this example here: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/application-composer/README.html

I am using an @Module annotation to provide PersistenceUnit java object as opposed to a 'test' persistence.xml file and I am overriding the provider to use hibernate (for specific reasons) as below.

```
unit.setProvider(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
```

Using version 4.2.11.Final version of Hibernate this works fine, but in upgrading to 4.3.8.Final i am now getting an IllegalArgumentException stating that no persistence.xml exists.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [FullParthToMyJar.jar:file:FullParthToMyJar.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml] referenced by given URL [file:FullParthToMyJar/jar:file:FullParthToMyJar.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml] does not exist
```

Is there anyway to stop this scanning from occuring as my project maven enforcer plugin is forcing me to use the later version.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely there is. Can you post the entire stack trace, your test case code, and your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, but we ended up using a persistence.xml file to avoid losing time, which fixed the issue.